# Generate Tables from ER Diagram Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, entity-relationship, diagram, management-studio-express, forward-engineer

I have developed an ER diagram using Microsoft SQL Server management studio. Is there any way to generate tables from that ER diagram? (Forward Engineering) In MySQL this thing can be done using MySQL Workbench. But my DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any function in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to forward engineer (Generate tables from ER Diagram) But Management Studio does it automatically when you are designing the database as the ER diagram.